# Преобразование списка в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Получаю список с данными из БД в таком виде. Kоличество словарей в списке может быть произвольным:

```
 result = [{'name': 'CPG_17_002', 'dnorpattern': '94009'}, 
           {'name': 'CPG_17_002', 'dnorpattern': '94011'}, 
           {'name': 'CPG_17_001', 'dnorpattern': '94004'}, 
           {'name': 'CPG_17_001', 'dnorpattern': '94005'}, 
           {'name': 'CPG_17_000', 'dnorpattern': '94007'}, 
           {'name': 'CPG_17_000', 'dnorpattern': '94010'}, 
           {'name': 'CPG_17_000', 'dnorpattern': '94012'}]
```

Для дальнейшей обработки и представления данных, данный список необходимо переобразовать в словарь вида:

```
{'CPG_17_002': ['94009', '94011'],
 'CPG_17_001': ['94004', '94005']
 'CPG_17_000': ['94007', '94010', '94012']
}
```

Ни как не могу сообразить, как написать условие проверки на равенство значений ключей `name` в списке для формирования итогового словаря.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = [{'name': 'CPG_17_002', 'dnorpattern': '94009'}, 
         {'name': 'CPG_17_002', 'dnorpattern': '94011'}, 
         {'name': 'CPG_17_001', 'dnorpattern': '94004'}, 
         {'name': 'CPG_17_001', 'dnorpattern': '94005'}, 
         {'name': 'CPG_17_000', 'dnorpattern': '94007'}, 
         {'name': 'CPG_17_000', 'dnorpattern': '94010'}, 
         {'name': 'CPG_17_000', 'dnorpattern': '94012'}]

d = {}
for i in result:
  if i['name'] not in d:
    d[i['name']] = [i['dnorpattern']]
  else:
    d[i['name']].append(i['dnorpattern'])

print(d)

#{
#  'CPG_17_002': ['94009', '94011'], 
#  'CPG_17_001': ['94004', '94005'], 
#  'CPG_17_000': ['94007', '94010', '94012']
#}
```

Comment: Вот жеж... даже обидно, что все так просто и очивидно:(

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать метод словаря `.get`

```
res_dict = {}
for item in result:
    name = item['name']
    value = item['dnorpattern']
    res_dict[name] = res_dict.get(name, []) + [value]
```

либо вместо словаря взять `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

res_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in result:
    name = item['name']
    value = item['dnorpattern']
    res_dict[name].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение с использованием [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

res = df.groupby("name")["dnorpattern"].apply(lambda x: x.to_list()).to_dict()
```

Результат:

```
In [15]: res
Out[15]:
{'CPG_17_000': ['94007', '94010', '94012'],
 'CPG_17_001': ['94004', '94005'],
 'CPG_17_002': ['94009', '94011']}
```

Пошагово:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
  dnorpattern        name
0       94009  CPG_17_002
1       94011  CPG_17_002
2       94004  CPG_17_001
3       94005  CPG_17_001
4       94007  CPG_17_000
5       94010  CPG_17_000
6       94012  CPG_17_000

In [17]: df.groupby("name")["dnorpattern"].apply(lambda x: x.to_list())
Out[17]:
name
CPG_17_000    [94007, 94010, 94012]
CPG_17_001           [94004, 94005]
CPG_17_002           [94009, 94011]
Name: dnorpattern, dtype: object

In [18]: df.groupby("name")["dnorpattern"].apply(lambda x: x.to_list()).to_dict()
Out[18]:
{'CPG_17_000': ['94007', '94010', '94012'],
 'CPG_17_001': ['94004', '94005'],
 'CPG_17_002': ['94009', '94011']}
```